# woocommerce generating more sessions than users

Tags: session, woocommerce

This is my first WooCommerce install so maybe I'm misunderstanding what is going on, but what I can see from Google Analytics is a site I put live last Friday had ~7500 sessions for yesterday, yet the session count (from _wp_session_expriry% query) in the wp_options table there would appear to be around 50000 sessions generated in the last 12 hours, since I wiped all sessions. I wiped the sessions because out of the box this table has no indexes and yet WooCommerce is hitting it with a mass of session data, but then the killer was the regular delete of transient data by WooCommerce. It turned out each of these deletes was taking over a minute with 300000 sessions in the table because the queries contained LIKEs.

So far I've check that robots are not going crazy, and rummaged in the Apache logs, and while I have some IPs with very high hit counts, I can't see why I would get new sessions for WooCommerce but not Google Analytics. Apache logs show actual page hits in line with Google Analytics page counts, so I suspect WooCommerce or plugins for the issue.

So for now I've reduced the problem by indexing wp_orders and reducing the session expiry time to 2 hours, BUT that doesn't explain why I have this crazy number of sessions in the first place.

I'm using the very latest of everything: WP 3.9, WC 2.1.7 +plus some other WC plugins, one of which appends to the WC session (WooCommerce Currency Switcher), but it looks like it's just hooking cleanly into the session management.

So I've got one big question and then a more architectural one:

The big one is: Can anyone suggest why I'm getting so many sessions in wp_options compared to GA users (order of magnitude)? And I'm much more confident

And then: Is there a clean way to move WC sessions into a separate table? wp_options doesn't seem like the obvious choice given how everything else is using it for lots of CRUD actions, which need to be responsive, I'd expect to see a woocommerce_sessions table.

Answer (score 1):

In `Woocommerce > System Status > Tools`, **Clear all sessions**

Answer (score 1):

The solution in to clear the sessions in

```
Woocommerce > System Status > Tools, Clear all sessions
```

And also change your Robots.txt to exclude bots from starting a Woo-Cart :)
Search engine bots scan all the products "add to cart" button causing it to create a bunch of extra cart sessions.

Change your robots.txt; add this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*add-to-cart=*
```

What I'd like is for woocommerce to auto-clean this mess!

Answer (score 1):

We're having this issue, the database was 1.3GB! When it's that large, the above method of using the "clear all sessions" chokes. You need to run a query in mySQL (several times until they are all cleared):

```
DELETE FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name LIKE '_wc_session_%' OR option_name LIKE '_wc_session_expires_%'
LIMIT 500
```

Or a plugin like this one might help: http://shop.webaware.com.au/downloads/delete-expired-transients/