# WP_Options table in MySQL database is over 360Mb - can I reduce the size by deleting WC_sessions?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress/woocommerce store and I am trying to clean things up a bit as it is very sluggish on the backend.

While investigating I found that my wp_options table alone is over 360 MB in size (I don't know what normal is but that seems large) By doing random spot checks, it seems to be almost entirely full of woocommerce sessions like this:
_wc_session_119a59e205553cc7d91bbf19b0b64768 and wc_max_related which have no expiration.

- I used woocommerce->system status->tools to delete all expired wc transient
- I installed the Transients Manager plugin and deleted all expired transients but it only removed about 300 entries. It still reports 7,300 transients (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXmNw.jpg)

That seems like a lot considering I have only had about 30 customers in the last 2 or 3 days and i am concerned that that is slowing my admin panel. Is it safe to delete all wc_sessions at a time when there is no-one currently on the site? If so, do I do that by doing 'clear all sessions' in woocommerce->system status->tools? I don't want to delete customer orders or anything like that but my understanding is that these are just open carts etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not include which version of WooCommerce you are running but there are usually 2 reasons why there are more customer sessions than expected:

1. CRON tasks not working
2. Bots visiting the site and creating multiple sessions

A customer session is stored for a period of 48 hours in WooCommerce.

Remedies to your situation are posted in this stackoverflow question:
[woocommerce generating more sessions than users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353347/woocommerce-generating-more-sessions-than-users)

Comment: I think you hit it right on the head with CRON tasks not working. That appears to be the case. Thank you!!!

Comment: I followed the advice in the recommended post and by clearing all customer sessions in woocommerce->system status->tools my table file size went from 360MB down to 60mb! Now off to fix the cron issue....

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATE: With WooCommerce 2.5 woocommerce-large-sessions has been merged into core.

For some of my clients CRON tasks work and we blocked bots from the site's add-to-cart. wc_sessions are still out of control. I found this plugin which was created because storing wc_sessions in the wp_options table caused trouble with options caching.

This plugin moves wc_sessions out of wp_options and into it's own table and implements its own cleanup hourly.*

Plugin: https://github.com/kloon/woocommerce-large-sessions

- I just started using this so I will come back to confirm this is working.

Comment: I will be very interested to hear how this goes. After my experience with my wp_options table growing so enormous and how massively it seems to have affected my site performance I would love to find a better way, I will look into it, hope it works well. I cant help but wonder what else is in my tables that is affecting my site speed negatively.

Comment: After letting this run for a week now the results are in. The table is holding at about 52k rows with the max session_id at 75765. So the cron job is working. The plugin holds the session for I believe three (3) days.

Also, regardless of the size of this table performance on the site is great and there has been zero slow down!

Comment: Thanks, mind up voting my answer or better, accepting it as the answer?

Comment: Upvoted. Got a messsage that my reputation is too new/low to show it